# dropzonejs directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone along with angular to make a file upload application.

I'm getting an issue where dropzone doesn't know that the file has successfully been uploaded.

```
angular.module('dropZone', []).directive('dropZone', function() {

  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    restrict: 'E',
    element.dropzone({ 
        url: "upload",
        maxThumbnailFilesize: 100,
        paramName: "file",
        maxThumbnailFilesize: 5,
        previewTemplate: '<div id="dz-preview-template" class="dz-preview dz-file-preview"><div class="dz-details">       <div class="dz-filename"><span data-dz-name></span></div><div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div><img data-dz-thumbnail /></div><div class="dz-progress"><span class="dz-upload" data-dz-uploadprogress></span></div></div>',
        success : function(res , server){

        },
        error : function(e) {
        }
    });
  }
});
```

I'm not sure the directive is able to update the DOM.

Does anyone know of a reason and possible solution on how I can basically get the little tick to appear on successful file uploads?

Comment: Use ng-chow in your tick-img and set the related variable (e.g. `$scope.showTick`) to `true` in the success-function

Comment: The contents of previewTemplate aren't inserted into the DOM either.

Comment: Does _something_ of the dropzone works? All injections are right? No errors thrown in the console?

Comment: It all works fine. And I get data back from res and server just fine. Just dropzone doesn't seem to insert previewTemplate when there is a success.
The returned res object does have 'previewElement' and 'previewTemplate' objects too.